# How to add new root as parent for existing nodes in tree-store data in Extjs

Tags: extjs, treepanel, extjs6.5, treestore

I am working on a tree-combobox(tree-panel inside combobox) where I have a tree-store to load tree-combobox.

I want to provide the feature to select all, so want to add a new root which will be the parent for existing tree-store data.

**Tree-Store:**

```
var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
                        root: {
                            expanded: true,
                            children: [
                                { text: "Numbers", expanded: false, children: [
                                    { text: '1', leaf: true },
                                    { text: '2', leaf: true },
                                    { text: '3', leaf: true },
                                    { text: '4', leaf: true },
                                    { text: '5', leaf: true },
                                ] },
                                { text: "Letters", expanded: true, children: [
                                    { text: 'A', leaf: true },
                                    { text: 'B', leaf: true },
                                    { text: 'C', leaf: true },
                                    { text: 'D', leaf: true },
                                    { text: 'E', leaf: true },
                                ] },
                                { text: "Colors", expanded: false, children: [
                                    { text: 'Red', leaf: true },
                                    { text: 'Green', leaf: true },
                                    { text: 'Blue', leaf: true }
                                ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Does changing the root node to visible solves your problem? [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.TreeStore.html#cfg-rootVisible)

Comment: thanks @NAmorim, it did the trick for me..

Comment: glad to help ;)

Comment: @NAmorim, can we show tree root dynamically, right now I have set its config to rootVisible:true, I want to show it at some event.

Comment: but i need it in config as rootVisible: false, after that if we can show it?

Comment: I believe `treestore` has a method `setRootVisible(boolean)`

Comment: thanks @NAmorim, will let you know..